# How do I rotate an image around its center using Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, rotation, pygame-surface, pygame2

I had been trying to rotate an image around its center in using `pygame.transform.rotate()` but it's not working. Specifically the part that hangs is `rot_image = rot_image.subsurface(rot_rect).copy()`. I get the exception:

> `ValueError: subsurface rectangle outside surface area`

Here is the code used to rotate an image:

```
def rot_center(image, angle):
    """rotate an image while keeping its center and size"""
    orig_rect = image.get_rect()
    rot_image = pygame.transform.rotate(image, angle)
    rot_rect = orig_rect.copy()
    rot_rect.center = rot_image.get_rect().center
    rot_image = rot_image.subsurface(rot_rect).copy()
    return rot_image
```

Answer (score 144):

Short answer:

When you use [`pygame.transform.rotate`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.rotate) the size of the new rotated image is increased compared to the size of the original image. You must make sure that the rotated image is placed so that its center remains in the center of the non-rotated image. To do this, get the rectangle of the original image and set the position. Get the rectangle of the rotated image and set the center position through the center of the original rectangle.
Returns a tuple from the function `red_center`, with the rotated image and the bounding rectangle of the rotated image:

```py
def rot_center(image, angle, x, y):
    
    rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(image, angle)
    new_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(center = image.get_rect(center = (x, y)).center)

    return rotated_image, new_rect
```

Or write a function which rotates and `.blit` the image:

```py
def blitRotateCenter(surf, image, topleft, angle):

    rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(image, angle)
    new_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(center = image.get_rect(topleft = topleft).center)

    surf.blit(rotated_image, new_rect)
```

---

Long answer:

An image ([`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html)) can be rotated by [`pygame.transform.rotate`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.rotate).

If that is done progressively in a loop, then the image gets distorted and rapidly increases:

```py
while not done:

    # [...]

    image = pygame.transform.rotate(image, 1)
    screen.blit(image, pos)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

[image]

This is because the bounding rectangle of a rotated image is always greater than the bounding rectangle of the original image (except some rotations by multiples of 90 degrees).
The image gets distort because of the multiply copies. Each rotation generates a small error (inaccuracy). The sum of the errors is growing and the images decays.

That can be fixed by keeping the original image and "blit" an image which was generated by a single rotation operation form the original image.

```py
angle = 0
while not done:

    # [...]

    rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(image, angle)
    angle += 1

    screen.blit(rotated_image, pos)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

[image]

Now the image seems to arbitrary change its position, because the size of the image changes by the rotation and origin is always the top left of the bounding rectangle of the image.

This can be compensated by comparing the [axis aligned bounding box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box) of the image before the rotation and after the rotation.
For the following math [`pygame.math.Vector2`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html) is used. Note in screen coordinates the y points down the screen, but the mathematical y axis points form the bottom to the top. This causes that the y axis has to be "flipped" during calculations

Set up a list with the 4 corner points of the bounding box:

```py
w, h = image.get_size()
box = [pygame.math.Vector2(p) for p in [(0, 0), (w, 0), (w, -h), (0, -h)]]
```

Rotate the vectors to the corner points by [`pygame.math.Vector2.rotate`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.rotate):

```py
box_rotate = [p.rotate(angle) for p in box]
```

Get the minimum and the maximum of the rotated points:

```py
min_box = (min(box_rotate, key=lambda p: p[0])[0], min(box_rotate, key=lambda p: p[1])[1])
max_box = (max(box_rotate, key=lambda p: p[0])[0], max(box_rotate, key=lambda p: p[1])[1])
```

Calculate the "compensated" origin of the upper left point of the image by adding the minimum of the rotated box to the position. For the y coordinate `max_box[1]` is the minimum, because of the "flipping" along the y axis:

```py
origin = (pos[0] + min_box[0], pos[1] - max_box[1])

rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(image, angle)
screen.blit(rotated_image, origin)
```

[image]

It is even possible to define a pivot on the original image. Compute the offset vector from the center of the image to the pivot and rotate the vector. A vector can be represented by [`pygame.math.Vector2`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) and can be rotated with [`pygame.math.Vector2.rotate`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.rotate). Notice that `pygame.math.Vector2.rotate` rotates in the opposite direction than `pygame.transform.rotate`. Therefore the angle has to be inverted:

Compute the vector from the center of the image to the pivot:

```py
image_rect = image.get_rect(topleft = (pos[0] - originPos[0], pos[1]-originPos[1]))
offset_center_to_pivot = pygame.math.Vector2(pos) - image_rect.center
```

Rotate the vector

```py
rotated_offset = offset_center_to_pivot.rotate(-angle)
```

Calculate the center of the rotated image:

```py
rotated_image_center = (pos[0] - rotated_offset.x, pos[1] - rotated_offset.y)
```

Rotate and blit the image:

```py
rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(image, angle)
rotated_image_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(center = rotated_image_center)

screen.blit(rotated_image, rotated_image_rect)
```

In the following example program, the function `blitRotate(surf, image, pos, originPos, angle)` does all the above steps and "blit" a rotated image to a surface.

- `surf` is the target Surface
- `image` is the Surface which has to be rotated and `blit`
- `pos` is the position of the pivot on the target Surface `surf` (relative to the top left of `surf`)
- `originPos` is position of the pivot on the `image` Surface (relative to the top left of `image`)
- `angle` is the angle of rotation in degrees

This means, the 2nd argument (`pos`) of `blitRotate` is the position of the pivot point in the window and the 3rd argument (`originPos`) is the position of the pivot point on the rotating *Surface*:

---

Minimal example: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-RotateAroundPivot](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-RotateAroundPivot#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def blitRotate(surf, image, pos, originPos, angle):

    # offset from pivot to center
    image_rect = image.get_rect(topleft = (pos[0] - originPos[0], pos[1]-originPos[1]))
    offset_center_to_pivot = pygame.math.Vector2(pos) - image_rect.center
    
    # roatated offset from pivot to center
    rotated_offset = offset_center_to_pivot.rotate(-angle)

    # roatetd image center
    rotated_image_center = (pos[0] - rotated_offset.x, pos[1] - rotated_offset.y)

    # get a rotated image
    rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(image, angle)
    rotated_image_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(center = rotated_image_center)

    # rotate and blit the image
    surf.blit(rotated_image, rotated_image_rect)
  
    # draw rectangle around the image
    pygame.draw.rect(surf, (255, 0, 0), (*rotated_image_rect.topleft, *rotated_image.get_size()),2)

def blitRotate2(surf, image, topleft, angle):

    rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(image, angle)
    new_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(center = image.get_rect(topleft = topleft).center)

    surf.blit(rotated_image, new_rect.topleft)
    pygame.draw.rect(surf, (255, 0, 0), new_rect, 2)

try:
    image = pygame.image.load('AirPlaneFront.png')
except:
    text = pygame.font.SysFont('Times New Roman', 50).render('image', False, (255, 255, 0))
    image = pygame.Surface((text.get_width()+1, text.get_height()+1))
    pygame.draw.rect(image, (0, 0, 255), (1, 1, *text.get_size()))
    image.blit(text, (1, 1))
w, h = image.get_size()

angle = 0
done = False
while not done:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    pos = (screen.get_width()/2, screen.get_height()/2)
    
    screen.fill(0)
    blitRotate(screen, image, pos, (w/2, h/2), angle)
    #blitRotate2(screen, image, pos, angle)
    angle += 1
    
    pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 255, 0), (pos[0]-20, pos[1]), (pos[0]+20, pos[1]), 3)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 255, 0), (pos[0], pos[1]-20), (pos[0], pos[1]+20), 3)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 255, 0), pos, 7, 0)

    pygame.display.flip()
    
pygame.quit()
exit()
```

---

See also [**Rotate surface**](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame/pygame_surface_rotate.md) and the answers to the questions:

- [How can you rotate an image around an off center pivot in Pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909942/how-can-you-rotate-an-image-around-an-off-center-pivot-in-pygame/59909946#59909946)
- [How to rotate an image around its center while its scale is getting larger(in Pygame)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54462645/how-to-rotate-an-image-around-its-center-while-its-scale-is-getting-largerin-py)
- [How to rotate an image(player) to the mouse direction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58603835/how-to-rotate-an-imageplayer-to-the-mouse-direction/58604116#58604116)
- [How to set the pivot point (center of rotation) for pygame.transform.rotate()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098900/how-to-set-the-pivot-point-center-of-rotation-for-pygame-transform-rotate/69312319#69312319)
- [How do you point the barrel towards mouse in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70283340/how-do-you-point-the-barrel-towards-mouse-in-pygame/70318324#70318324)

Comment: Out of scope from the original answer but definitely what I wanted. I like that this goes beyond the center and can pivot around a provide point. Great response in terms of doing even more than required.

Answer (score 8):

You are deleting the rect that rotate creates. You need to preserve rect, since it changes size when rotated.

If you want to preserve the objects location, do:

```py
def rot_center(image, angle):
    """rotate a Surface, maintaining position."""
    
    loc = image.get_rect().center  #rot_image is not defined 
    rot_sprite = pygame.transform.rotate(image, angle)
    rot_sprite.get_rect().center = loc
    return rot_sprite
    
    # or return tuple: (Surface, Rect)
    # return rot_sprite, rot_sprite.get_rect()
```

Answer (score 8):

There are some problems with the top answer: The position of the previous rect needs to be available in the function, so that we can assign it to the new rect, e.g.:

```
rect = new_image.get_rect(center=rect.center)
```

In the other answer the location is obtained by creating a new rect from the original image, but that means it will be positioned at the default (0, 0) coordinates.

The example below should work correctly. The new rect needs the `center` position of the old rect,  so we pass it as well to the function. Then rotate the image, call `get_rect` to get a new rect with the correct size and pass the `center` attribute of the old rect as the `center` argument. Finally, return both the rotated image and the new rect as a tuple and unpack it in the main loop.

```
import pygame as pg


def rotate(image, rect, angle):
    """Rotate the image while keeping its center."""
    # Rotate the original image without modifying it.
    new_image = pg.transform.rotate(image, angle)
    # Get a new rect with the center of the old rect.
    rect = new_image.get_rect(center=rect.center)
    return new_image, rect


def main():
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    gray = pg.Color('gray15')
    blue = pg.Color('dodgerblue2')

    image = pg.Surface((320, 200), pg.SRCALPHA)
    pg.draw.polygon(image, blue, ((0, 0), (320, 100), (0, 200)))
    # Keep a reference to the original to preserve the image quality.
    orig_image = image
    rect = image.get_rect(center=(320, 240))
    angle = 0

    done = False
    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True

        angle += 2
        image, rect = rotate(orig_image, rect, angle)

        screen.fill(gray)
        screen.blit(image, rect)
        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

---

Here's another example with a rotating pygame sprite.

```
import pygame as pg


class Entity(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pg.Surface((122, 70), pg.SRCALPHA)
        pg.draw.polygon(self.image, pg.Color('dodgerblue1'),
                        ((1, 0), (120, 35), (1, 70)))
        # A reference to the original image to preserve the quality.
        self.orig_image = self.image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.angle = 0

    def update(self):
        self.angle += 2
        self.rotate()

    def rotate(self):
        """Rotate the image of the sprite around its center."""
        # `rotozoom` usually looks nicer than `rotate`. Pygame's rotation
        # functions return new images and don't modify the originals.
        self.image = pg.transform.rotozoom(self.orig_image, self.angle, 1)
        # Create a new rect with the center of the old rect.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group(Entity((320, 240)))

    while True:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                return

        all_sprites.update()
        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        all_sprites.draw(screen)
        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

Comment: I'm using your method and it also seems to have some problems. It displays my image at the top-left corner of my screen (it still rotates at the center properly, hooray), but I don't want it there, and it has some strange things going on (the locations are the same but the destination is different). I can't explain it all here, and I might ask a question on it and include the link to this question and your answer.

Comment: @Ethanol I can't help without seeing your code. The examples above work correctly for me.

Comment: Actually, just one quick question that might help me: why do you assign `(320, 240)` in this `rect = image.get_rect(center=(320, 240))` to center? What does it do, and how would it affect the code if you removed it?

Comment: I'm setting the initial position of the `rect` there. The rect will have the size of the `image` and the `center` coordinates `(320, 240)`. The other coordinates like `topleft` (that's the actual blit position) will be adjusted accordingly. 

When the image is rotated and you call `get_rect` again, the size of the rect will be different, but by setting the center coords to the previous center coords, we automatically update the topleft position as well, so that the image will be blitted at the correct position.

Comment: @Ethanol have you figured it out? If yes, we could delete the comments here and I'd add some extra info to the answer.

Comment: Great answer! Works like a champ. In addition to rotating, I would like to move the sprite while maintaining the rotation... How would I add to your algorithm?

Answer (score 4):

Everything you need for drawing an image in `pygame`

```
game_display = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

x = 0
y = 0
angle = 0

img = pygame.image.load("resources/image.png")
img = pygame.transform.scale(img, (50, 50)) # image size

def draw_img(self, image, x, y, angle):
    rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(image, angle) 
    game_display.blit(rotated_image, rotated_image.get_rect(center=image.get_rect(topleft=(x, y)).center).topleft)

# run this method with your loop
def tick():
    draw_img(img, x, y, angle)
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem: Example works good, but needs equal dimensions for width and height. Fixed pictures and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I had to modify skrx solution as below, this way works for me.

```
angle=0
roll = true
while roll:
    # clean surface with your background color
    gameDisplay.fill(color)
    self.image = yourImage
    rotate_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, angle)
    rect = rotate_image.get_rect()
    pos = (((your_surface_width - rect.width)/2),((your_surface_height - rect.height)/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(rotate_image,pos)
    pygame.display.flip()
    angle+=2
    if angle == 360:
        roll=False
```

Answer (score 1):

Another important point when rotating an image is that the image must have an alpha channel. Many people use rectangular, uniformly filled surfaces to test their code, forgetting about the alpha channel. This results in what appears to be a randomly stretched rectangle. How to create a surface with an alpha channel is explained in the answer to the question: [pygame doesn't rotate surface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76966463/pygame-doesnt-rotate-surface/76966484#76966484). In the example I create the [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) with the `pygame.SRCALPHA` flag to get an image with an alpha channel:

```py
surface = pygame.Surface((100, 50), pygame.SRCAPLHA)
```

The second important thing is that you must never rotate a `pygame.Surface` object repeatedly, because this leads to an ever increasing `pygame.Surface` and distortions, but you must save the original surface and always create a rotated `pygame.Surface` from it. See the following example, where I use the [`pygame.sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) module:

[image]

```py
import pygame

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.original_image = image
        self.image = self.original_image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (x, y))
        self.angle = 0
    def update(self):
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.original_image, self.angle)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)
        self.angle = (self.angle + 1) % 360

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

surface = pygame.Surface((100, 50), pygame.SRCALPHA)
surface.fill("black")
player = Player(surface, *window.get_rect().center)
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group(player)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    all_sprites.update()

    window.fill((255, 255, 255))
    all_sprites.draw(window)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```