# How can you rotate an image around an off center pivot in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I want to rotate an image around a pivot, which is not in the center of the [Surface](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) in [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news).
The pivot is the green cross in the image:

[image]

I know the position of the pivot in the game window.
How do I track the image at this point and I rotate it around this point simultaneously.

```py
image = pygame.image.load("boomerang64.png")
pos = (200, 200)
angle = 0

while True:
    # [...]

    rotate_rect, rotate_image = ???? # rotate around green cross by angle 
    surf.blit(rotated_image, rotate_rect)
    angle += 1

    # [...]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First the position of the pivot on the `Surface` has to be defined:

```py
image = pygame.image.load("boomerang64.png") # 64x64 surface
pivot = (48, 21)                             # position of the pivot on the image
```

When an image is rotated, then its size increase. We have to compare the [axis aligned bounding box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box) of the image before the rotation and after the rotation.
For the following math [`pygame.math.Vector2`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html) is used. Note in screen coordinates the y points down the screen, but the mathematical y axis points form the bottom to the top. This causes that the y axis has to be "flipped" during calculations. Notice that `pygame.math.Vector2.rotate` rotates in the opposite direction than `pygame.transform.rotate`. Therefore the angle has to be inverted.

Set up a list with the 4 corner points of the bounding box and rotate the vectors to the corner points by [`pygame.math.Vector2.rotate`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.rotate). Finally find the minimum of the rotated box. Since the y axis in pygame points downwards, this has to be compensated by finding the maximum of the rotated inverted height ("*max(rotate(-h))*"):

Compute the vector from the center of the image to the pivot:

```py
image_rect = image.get_rect(topleft = (pos[0] - originPos[0], pos[1]-originPos[1]))
offset_center_to_pivot = pygame.math.Vector2(pos) - image_rect.center
```

Rotate the offset vector:

```py
rotated_offset = offset_center_to_pivot.rotate(-angle)
```

Calculate the center of the rotated image:

```py
rotated_image_center = (pos[0] - rotated_offset.x, pos[1] - rotated_offset.y)
```

Rotate and blit the image:

```py
rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(image, angle)
rotated_image_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(center = rotated_image_center)

screen.blit(rotated_image, rotated_image_rect)
```

In the following example program, the function `blitRotate(surf, image, pos, originPos, angle)` does all the above steps and [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) a rotated image to the Surface which is associated to the display:

- `surf` is the target Surface
- `image` is the Surface which has to be rotated and `blit`
- `pos` is the position of the pivot on the target Surface `surf` (relative to the top left of `surf`)
- `originPos` is position of the pivot on the `image` Surface (relative to the top left of `image`)
- `angle` is the angle of rotation in degrees

[image]

```py
import math
import pygame

def blitRotate(surf, image, pos, originPos, angle):
    image_rect = image.get_rect(topleft = (pos[0] - originPos[0], pos[1]-originPos[1]))
    offset_center_to_pivot = pygame.math.Vector2(pos) - image_rect.center
    rotated_offset = offset_center_to_pivot.rotate(-angle)
    rotated_image_center = (pos[0] - rotated_offset.x, pos[1] - rotated_offset.y)
    rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(image, angle)
    rotated_image_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(center = rotated_image_center)
    surf.blit(rotated_image, rotated_image_rect)
  
pygame.init()
size = (400,400)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

image = pygame.image.load('Boomerang64.png')
pivot = (48, 21)

angle, frame = 0, 0
done = False
while not done:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
    screen.fill(0)

    pos = (200 + math.cos(frame * 0.05)*100, 200 + math.sin(frame * 0.05)*50)
    blitRotate(screen, image, pos, pivot, angle)

    pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 255, 0), (pos[0]-20, pos[1]), (pos[0]+20, pos[1]), 3)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 255, 0), (pos[0], pos[1]-20), (pos[0], pos[1]+20), 3)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 255, 0), pos, 7, 0)

    pygame.display.flip()
    frame += 1
    angle += 10
    
pygame.quit()
exit()
```

---

The same algorithm can be used for a [Sprite](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite), too.
In that case the position (`self.pos`), pivot (`self.pivot`) and angle (`self.angle`) are instance attributes of the class.
In the `update` method the `self.rect` and `self.image` attributes are computed.

Minimal example: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-RotateSpriteAroundOffCenterPivot](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-RotateSpriteAroundOffCenterPivot#main.py)</kbd>

```py
import math
import pygame

class SpriteRotate(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, imageName, origin, pivot):
        super().__init__() 
        self.image = pygame.image.load(imageName)
        self.original_image = self.image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (origin[0]-pivot[0], origin[1]-pivot[1]))
        self.origin = origin
        self.pivot = pivot
        self.angle = 0

    def update(self):
        
        # offset from pivot to center
        image_rect = self.original_image.get_rect(topleft = (self.origin[0] - self.pivot[0], self.origin[1]-self.pivot[1]))
        offset_center_to_pivot = pygame.math.Vector2(self.origin) - image_rect.center
        
        # roatated offset from pivot to center
        rotated_offset = offset_center_to_pivot.rotate(-self.angle)

        # roatetd image center
        rotated_image_center = (self.pos[0] - rotated_offset.x, self.pos[1] - rotated_offset.y)

        # get a rotated image
        self.image  = pygame.transform.rotate(self.original_image, self.angle)
        self.rect   = self.image.get_rect(center = rotated_image_center)
        self.angle += 10
  
pygame.init()
size = (400,400)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

boomerang = SpriteRotate('Boomerang64.png', (200, 200), (48, 21))
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group(boomerang)

frame = 0
done = False
while not done:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
    
    pos = (200 + math.cos(frame * 0.05)*100, 200 + math.sin(frame * 0.05)*50)
    boomerang.pos = pos
    all_sprites.update()

    screen.fill(0)
    
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    #pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 255, 0), (pos[0]-20, pos[1]), (pos[0]+20, pos[1]), 3)
    #pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 255, 0), (pos[0], pos[1]-20), (pos[0], pos[1]+20), 3)
    #pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 255, 0), pos, 7, 0)

    pygame.display.flip()
    frame += 1
    
pygame.quit()
exit()
```

---

[How do I rotate an image around its center using Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183208/how-do-i-rotate-an-image-around-its-center-using-pygame)
[How to rotate an image around its center while its scale is getting larger(in Pygame)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54462645/how-to-rotate-an-image-around-its-center-while-its-scale-is-getting-largerin-py)