# Getting rotated rect of rotated image in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I have a problem about pygame rect.

The rect isn't like what I want.

I saw I can do this with sprite class. But I don't want use sprites.
I didn't understand differences of Sprite Rect and Image Rect.

[I want to get rect like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ka1Xs.png)
[image]

[But I am getting like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZxcy.png)
[image]

Here is my rect function:

```
def getRect(self):
    return self.image.get_rect(center=(self.x,self.y))
```

Image is rotationed image.

I haven't very well english, I've told you as much as I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) returns a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object. A `pygame.Rect` stores a position and a size. It is always axis aligned and cannot represent a rotated rectangle.

Use [`pygame.math.Vector2.rotate()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.rotate) to compute the corner points of the rotated rectangle. `orig_image` is the image before it is roatated:

```py
rect = orig_image.get_rect(center = (self.x, self.y))

pivot = pygame_math.Vector2(self.x, self.y)

p0 = (pygame.math.Vector2(rect.topleft) - pivot).rotate(-angle) + pivot 
p1 = (pygame.math.Vector2(rect.topright) - pivot).rotate(-angle) + pivot 
p2 = (pygame.math.Vector2(rect.bottomright) - pivot).rotate(-angle) + pivot 
p3 = (pygame.math.Vector2(rect.bottomleft) - pivot).rotate(-angle) + pivot
```

Use [`pygame.draw.lines()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.line) to draw the rotated rectangle:

```py
pygame.draw.lines(screen, (255, 255, 0), True, [p0, p1, p2, p3], 3)
```

---

See also [How do I rotate an image around its center using PyGame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183208/how-do-i-rotate-an-image-around-its-center-using-pygame/54714144#54714144) and [How can you rotate an image around an off center pivot in PyGame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909942/how-can-you-rotate-an-image-around-an-off-center-pivot-in-pygame/59909946#59909946/59909946#59909946).

---

Minimal example: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-RotatedRectangle](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-RotatedRectangle#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 50)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

orig_image = font.render("rotated rectangle", True, (255, 0, 0))
angle = 30
rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(orig_image, angle)

def draw_rect_angle(surf, rect, pivot, angle):
    pts = [rect.topleft, rect.topright, rect.bottomright, rect.bottomleft]
    pts = [(pygame.math.Vector2(p) - pivot).rotate(-angle) + pivot for p in pts]
    pygame.draw.lines(surf, (255, 255, 0), True, pts, 3)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False    

    window.fill(0)
    window_center = window.get_rect().center
    window.blit(rotated_image, rotated_image.get_rect(center = window_center))
    rect = orig_image.get_rect(center = window_center)
    draw_rect_angle(window, rect, window_center, angle)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: Thanks very much. How can I check if an object in its rect?

Comment: Can I convert it to a class?
Because I want to check if an object in its rect.
Example:
    hitbox = RotationedRect(image,angle)
    if hitbox.collide(hitbox2):
        ...

Comment: @Arda You can put any code you want in a class.However, you need to implement your own collision algorithm. I recommend to use mask collision. See [Pygame mask collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60077813/pygame-mask-collision/60078039#60078039)

Comment: Okay, I will try make a class. Thanks.