# How do I make an object in pygame rotate

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, game-physics, pygame-surface

I am making a game, and previously had made it using images and bliting them but I am now remaking it trying to uses object and sprites. I am unsure how I would make my image and rect rotate and I am also unsure how to create a rect that is behind or none visible around my object as I plan to have two cars that can collide.
I previously used sin and cos to calculate the direction and the image would turn when I clicked the left and right arrow but I don't know how to apply this to an object class.
Any help would be appreciated thanks.

This is my code

```
import pygame, random
#Let's import the Car Class
from Car import Car
pygame.init()


speed = 1

SCREENWIDTH=800
SCREENHEIGHT=600
 
size = (SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Car Racing")
 
#This will be a list that will contain all the sprites we intend to use in our game.
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
 

playerCar = Car(60, 80, 70)
playerCar.rect.x = 160
playerCar.rect.y = 100

 
# Add the car to the list of objects
all_sprites_list.add(playerCar)


#Allowing the user to close the window...
carryOn = True
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
 
while carryOn:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                carryOn=False
            elif event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key==pygame.K_x:
                     playerCar.moveRight(10)
 
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            playerCar.moveLeft(5)
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            playerCar.moveRight(5)
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            playerCar.moveUp(5)
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            playerCar.moveDown(5)


        all_sprites_list.update()
 
        #Drawing on Screen
        screen.fill("white")
 
        #Now let's draw all the sprites in one go. (For now we only have 1 sprite!)
        all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
 
        #Refresh Screen
        pygame.display.flip()
 
        #Number of frames per secong e.g. 60
        clock.tick(60)
 
pygame.quit()
```

###second file###

```
import pygame
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
 
class Car(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    #This class represents a car. It derives from the "Sprite" class in Pygame.
 
    def __init__(self, width, height, speed):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super().__init__()
        
        # Instead we could load a proper picture of a car...
        self.image = pygame.image.load("car.png").convert_alpha()
        

        #Initialise attributes of the car.
        self.width=width
        self.height=height
        #self.speed = speed
 
        # Draw the car (a rectangle!)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, (0, 0, 0, 0), [0, 0, self.width, self.height])
 
        # Fetch the rectangle object that has the dimensions of the image.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
 
    def moveRight(self, pixels):
        self.rect.x += pixels
 
    def moveLeft(self, pixels):
        self.rect.x -= pixels
 
    def moveUp(self, pixels):
        self.rect.y -= pixels
 
    def moveDown(self, pixels):
        self.rect.y += pixels
 
    def changeSpeed(self, speed):
        self.speed = speed
```

Answer (score 2):

> I am also unsure how to create a rect that is behind or none visible around my object.

If you don't draw an object it is not visible. Don't confuse a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) objects and [`pygame.draw.rect`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html). However, a `pygame.Rect` stores a position and a size. It is always axis aligned and cannot represent a rotated rectangle.

I'm suspect you need the rectangular outline of the objects for collision detection. See [How do I detect collision in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640685/how-do-i-detect-collision-in-pygame/65064907#65064907), [Collision between masks in PyGame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55817422/collision-between-masks-in-pygame/55818093#55818093) and [Pygame mask collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60077813/pygame-mask-collision/60078039#60078039).

[image]

---

Use [`pygame.transform.rotate`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.rotate) to rotate an image. e.g:

```py
def blitRotateCenter(surf, image, center, angle):

    rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(image, angle)
    new_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(center = image.get_rect(center = center).center)

    surf.blit(rotated_image, new_rect)
```

See also [How do I rotate an image around its center using PyGame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183208/how-do-i-rotate-an-image-around-its-center-using-pygame/54714144#54714144)

[image]

---

If you want to rotate a rectangle you have to fill a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object with transparency information with a uniform color and rotate the surface. Set the `SRCALPHA` to crate a *Surface* with per pixel alpha format:

```py
rect_surf = pygame.Surface((width, height), pygame.SRCALPHA)
rect_surf.fill(color)
blitRotateCenter(screen, rect_surf, (x, y), angle)
```

See also [Getting rotated rect of rotated image in Pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66984521/getting-rotated-rect-of-rotated-image-in-pygame/66984713#66984713)

[image]