# image and rect of a image are not on top of each other, they are shifted. what is wrong

Tags: python, pygame

When I draw the image and the rect Wof the images, then the upper left corner of the rectangle is exactly in the center of the image.

```py
def blitRotateCenter(image, left, top, angle):
    rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(image, angle)
    new_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(center = image.get_rect(center = (left, top)).center)
    screen.blit(rotated_image, new_rect)
```

```py
self.image = pygame.image.load("Bilder/car.png")   
self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    
blitRotateCenter(auto.image, auto.rect.x, auto.rect.y, auto.wagen_winkel)
draw.rect(screen,red,auto.rect)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Also, please share any screenshots to better explain your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return `new_rect` from `blitRotateCenter` and use it to draw the  rectangle:

```py
def blitRotateCenter(image, left, top, angle):
    rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(image, angle)
    new_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(center = image.get_rect(center = (left, top)).center)
    screen.blit(rotated_image, new_rect)
    return new_rect
```

```py
new_auto_rect = blitRotateCenter(auto.image, auto.rect.x, auto.rect.y, auto.wagen_winkel)
draw.rect(screen,red, new_auto_rect)
```

However, if you want to draw a rotated rectangle, see [Getting rotated rect of rotated image in Pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66984521/getting-rotated-rect-of-rotated-image-in-pygame/66984713#66984713).

Comment: But i cannot use the new_auto_rect for collision detected.What can i manage it?

Comment: Why can't you use it for collision detection?

Comment: Why can't you use it for collision detection?  You can store `new_auto_rect` in `self.rect`. `self.rect = new_auto_rect`. Or do you search for [PyGame collision with masks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57455811/pygame-collision-with-masks/57499484#57499484)?

Comment: i set auto.rect = new_auto_rect. But the the image run over the screen. I think i need to center it? Where?   if it works i want to use hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide( auto, land, False, pygame.sprite.collide_mask)

Comment: @Joachim No you do not need to center it. It is centered. It is used to draw a rectangle on the screen. Theres is something messed up in your code. I suggest to ask a new question.