# Sprite Is Not Rotating Towards The Player Properly How Do I Fix This?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I am trying to make my sprites rotate towards the player, but the rotation is out of place. Here is a [video of the behaviour](https://gyazo.com/3d035e5f632cc98a0b1412edb934afd6).

I am not sure how to fix this,

## Sprite class

```py
  #-------------------------------- enemy shoots left and right

    shotsright = pygame.image.load("canss.png")
    class enemyshoot:
        def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
            self.x = x
            self.y =y
            self.height = height
            self.width = width
            self.color = color
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
            self.health = 10
            self.hitbox = (self.x + -20, self.y + 30, 31, 57)
           #-------------------------------------------------------
            # Make a Reference Copy of the bitmap for later rotation
            self.shootsright = pygame.image.load("canss.png")
            self.shootsright = pygame.transform.scale(self.shootsright,(self.shootsright.get_width()-150,self.shootsright.get_height()-150))            
            self.image    = self.shootsright
            self.rect     = self.image.get_rect()
            self.position = pygame.math.Vector2( (200, 180) )
            self.isLookingAtPlayer = False
        def draw(self):
            self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
            window.blit(self.image, self.rect)
            self.hits = (self.x + 20, self.y, 28,60)
            pygame.draw.rect(window, (255,0,0), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 60, 100, 10)) # NEW
            pygame.draw.rect(window, (0,255,0), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 60, 100 - (5 * (10 - self.health)), 10))
            self.hitbox = (self.x + 200, self.y + 200, 51, 65)
        def lookAt( self, coordinate ):
            # Rotate image to point in the new direction
            delta_vector  = coordinate - self.position
            radius, angle = delta_vector.as_polar()
            self.image    = pygame.transform.rotate(self.shootsright, -angle)
            # Re-set the bounding rectangle and position since 
            # the dimensions and centroid will have (probably) changed.
            current_pos      = self.rect.center
            self.rect        = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.center = current_pos
            


            
    black = (0,0,0)
    enemyshooting = []
    platformGroup = pygame.sprite.Group
    platformList = []
    level = ["                                                                                                                     p               p           p                         p                        p        ",
             "                                       ",
             "                             ",
             "                                      ",
             "                                  ",
             "                           ",
             "                                      ",
             "                                      ",
             "                                    ",
             "                                   ",
             "                    ",]
    for iy, row in enumerate(level):
        for ix, col in enumerate(row):
            if col == "p":
                new_platforms = enemyshoot(ix*10, iy*50, 10,10,(255,255,255))
                enemyshooting.append(new_platforms)
```

this is the rotating part

```
class enemyshoot:
     def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
       # [................]
           #-------------------------------------------------------
            # Make a Reference Copy of the bitmap for later rotation
            self.shootsright = pygame.image.load("canss.png")
            self.shootsright = pygame.transform.scale(self.shootsright,(self.shootsright.get_width()-150,self.shootsright.get_height()-150))            
            self.image    = self.shootsright
            self.rect     = self.image.get_rect()
            self.position = pygame.math.Vector2( (200, 180) )      


        def lookAt( self, coordinate ):
            # Rotate image to point in the new direction
            delta_vector  = coordinate - pygame.math.Vector2(self.rect.center)
            radius, angle = delta_vector.as_polar()
            self.image    = pygame.transform.rotate(self.shootsright, -angle)
            # Re-set the bounding rectangle and position since 
            # the dimensions and centroid will have (probably) changed.
            current_pos      = self.rect.center
            self.rect        = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.center = current_pos
```

This is where I call the `LookAt` function to face the player:

```
      # so instead of this 
            for enemyshoot in enemyshooting:
                if not enemyshoot.isLookingAtPlayer:
                    enemyshoot.lookAt((playerman.x, playerman.y))
```

The rotation is out of place, and I can't figure out how to fix it. I am trying to make the mouth of the cannon rotate towards the player because that's where the bullets will append from.

Comment: You need to make a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which is something we can run and debug. Without that, we can't help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I concur with everything @Rabbid76 says in the above answer.

I suspect part of your problem may be that the "human readable" part of the bitmap is not centered around the bitmap's [centroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid).  Thus when rotated, it "sweeps" through an arc, rather than being rotated "around itself".  (The preserving of the centre co-ordinate is an important step here to maintain a smooth rotation about the centroid of the object).

Consider the two bitmaps (the image on the right has a large 3/4 transparent section top-left):

[image: centred image]   [image: off-centred image]

Both are rotated around their centroid, but since the visible part on the 2nd image is not centred, it rotates weirdly.

[image: example video]

So ensure your actual bitmap is centred within itself.

Reference Code:

```
import pygame
import random

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH    = 800
WINDOW_HEIGHT   = 400
WINDOW_SURFACE  = pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE

DARK_BLUE = (   3,   5,  54 )

class RotationSprite( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    def __init__( self, image, x, y, ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.original = image
        self.image    = image
        self.rect     = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = ( x, y )
        # for maintaining trajectory
        self.position    = pygame.math.Vector2( ( x, y ) )
        self.velocity    = pygame.math.Vector2( ( 0, 0 ) )

    def lookAt( self, co_ordinate ):
        # Rotate image to point in the new direction
        delta_vector  = co_ordinate - self.position
        radius, angle = delta_vector.as_polar()
        self.image    = pygame.transform.rotozoom( self.original, -angle, 1 )
        # Re-set the bounding rectagle
        current_pos      = self.rect.center
        self.rect        = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = current_pos



### initialisation
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), WINDOW_SURFACE )
pygame.display.set_caption( "Rotation Example" )

### Missiles!
rotation_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
rotation_image1 = pygame.image.load( 'rot_offcentre_1.png' )
rotation_image2 = pygame.image.load( 'rot_offcentre_2.png' )
rotation_sprites.add( RotationSprite( rotation_image1, WINDOW_WIDTH//3, WINDOW_HEIGHT//2 ) )
rotation_sprites.add( RotationSprite( rotation_image2, 2*( WINDOW_WIDTH//3 ), WINDOW_HEIGHT//2 ) )


### Main Loop
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False
while not done:

    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True
        elif ( event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP ):
            # On mouse-click
            pass

    # Record mouse movements for positioning the paddle
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    for m in rotation_sprites:
        m.lookAt( mouse_pos )
    rotation_sprites.update()

    # Update the window, but not more than 60 FPS
    window.fill( DARK_BLUE )
    rotation_sprites.draw( window )
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Clamp FPS
    clock.tick_busy_loop(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: I have already tried that I am not sure what you mean by centering it currently I followed the example you showed but I am still having rotation problem [VIDEO](https://gyazo.com/7f36da47929faf61c5cb5303f0d6e9ea)  it only rotates slightly when the player is jumping    [script](https://pastebin.com/tUbNTZf9)

Answer (score 1):

`self.position` is set in the constructor, but it is not updated. Use the `self.rect.center` to compute the direction vector:

```py
delta_vector = coordinate - pygame.math.Vector2(self.rect.center)
```

Use `math.atan2` to compute the angle of rotation:
(See [How do I make my player rotate towards mouse position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56627414/how-do-i-make-my-player-rotate-towards-mouse-position/56627834#56627834))

```py
angle = (180 / math.pi) * math.atan2(-delta_vector.x, -delta_vector.y)
```

Setting the rectangle position in `draw` struggles with rotating the sprite in `lookAt`. Note the size of the rotated rectangle is enlarged. See [How do I rotate an image around its center using Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183208/how-do-i-rotate-an-image-around-its-center-using-pygame/54714144#54714144).

I recommend to set the look-at position in `lookAt` and to compute the rotated image in `draw`:

```py
class enemyshoot:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
       # [...]

       self.look_at_pos = (x, y)

    def draw(self):
   
        self.rect = self.shootsright.get_rect(topleft = (self.x, self.y))

        dx = self.look_at_pos[0] - self.rect.centerx
        dy = self.look_at_pos[1] - self.rect.centery 
        angle = (180 / math.pi) * math.atan2(-dx, -dy)

        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.shootsright, angle)
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)

        window.blit(self.image, self.rect)
        self.hits = (self.x + 20, self.y, 28,60)
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (255,0,0), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 60, 100, 10)) # NEW
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (0,255,0), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 60, 100 - (5 * (10 - self.health)), 10))
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 200, self.y + 200, 51, 65)

    def lookAt(self, coordinate):
        self.look_at_pos = coordinate
```

Comment: I think the rotation became worse [vide](https://gyazo.com/4f4ef23e720df5ae0a290645f8c42616)

Comment: so instead of saying for enemyshoot in enemyshooting:                 if not enemyshoot.isLookingAtPlayer:                     enemyshoot.lookAt((playerman.x, playerman.y)) I could give it an update def at the bottom of the enemyshoot class* I updated the thread instead of getting the mouse position how could I get the player poisition to make it move like that?   for proper rotating? [script](https://pastebin.com/UcMUJjzs)

Comment: I am getting an error `enemyshoot.lookAt((playerman.x, playerman.y))
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable` I dont see anything wrong with my [enemyshoot class](https://pastebin.com/A21ZZx5p)

Comment: @HabibIsmail My bad. Of course the name of the attribute and the function has to be different. I've changed `self.lookAt` -> `self.look_at_pos`

Comment: `    enemyshoot.lookAt((playerman.x, playerman.y))
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable`  getting the same error again

Comment: @HabibIsmail Then did it wrong. Please read the answer carefully.

Comment: oh I fixed sorry but [video](https://gyazo.com/c143bce94977d2ebb7bb9c2a29b6d285) look its rotating nice but its moving up [update version of the script[(https://pastebin.com/0454qB2M)

Comment: @HabibIsmail Try `angle = (180/math.pi) * math.atan2(-dy, dx)` or `angle = (180/math.pi) * math.atan2(dy, dx)`

Comment: II forgot to do `self.look_at_pos = coordinate`
 ok I have tried the first one it works better then the second one but there is still rotation problem [video](https://gyazo.com/050b426bf547e4091377c333f8abdcdf)      what I have done [script](https://pastebin.com/AmzQY872)