# How to rotate an image(player) to the mouse direction?

Tags: python, pygame

Im thinking about making a 2d shooting game in pygame and i want to make my player(Player_1) point to the mouse direction.I looked for a solution for hours and tried all solution i could find but none had worked so can you pls help me ?
Here's my code:

```py
import pygame, sys, os
from pygame.locals import *
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'
pygame.init()
#Exit settings
def quit():
  pygame.quit()
  sys.quit()
def events():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
            quit()

#IDS
CLOCK=pygame.time.Clock()
FPS=120
DS=pygame.display.set_mode((0,0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
pygame.display.set_caption("Shooting simulator")
W,H=DS.get_size()
P_X=W/2-50
P_Y=H/2-50

#Colors
Red=pygame.Color("#FF0000")
Blue=pygame.Color("#0000FF")
Green=pygame.Color("#00FF00")
Black=pygame.Color("#000000")
White=pygame.Color("#FFFFFF")

#IGT(in game things)
Player_1=pygame.image.load("Img/Player_1.png").convert()

def game_loop():
  while True:
    events()

    DS.fill(White)
    DS.blit(Player_1,(P_X,P_Y))
    pygame.display.flip()
game_loop()
```

[This is my player(Player_1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KW55p.png)
[image]

I will really appreciate all help.

Comment: Yes thats exactly what i wanted, thanks for all your help and Im sorry to had waste your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to compute the angle of the vector from the player to the mouse. get the mouse position by [`pygame.mouse.get_pos()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pos) and the rectangle ([`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)) around the player:

```py
mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
player_rect = Player_1.get_rect(topleft=(P_X,P_Y))
```

Calculate the vector from the player to the mouse  and compute the angle of vector by [`math.atan2`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html). The y-axis needs to be reversed (`-dy`) as the y-axis is generally pointing up, but in the PyGame coordinate system the y-axis is pointing down.

```py
dx, dy = mx - player_rect.centerx, player_rect.centery - my
angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(-dy, dx)) - correction_angle
```

In addition, a correction angle must be deducted (`- correction_angle`). The correction angle depends on the *Sprite*. If the *Sprite*

[image] is looking to the right, the correction angle is 0: `correction_angle = 0`
[image] is looking up, the correction angle is 90: `correction_angle = 90`
[image] is looking to the left, the correction angle is 180: `correction_angle = 180`
[image] is looking down, the correction angle is 270: `correction_angle = 270`

Rotate the player with [`pygame.transform.rotate()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.rotate) by the angle around its center:
(See also [How do I rotate an image around its center using Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183208/how-do-i-rotate-an-image-around-its-center-using-pygame/54714144#54714144))

```py
rot_image = pygame.transform.rotate(Player_1, angle)
rot_image_rect = rot_image.get_rect(center=player_rect.center)
```

---

Minimal example: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-RotateWithMouse](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-RotateWithMouse#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

```py
import math
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
player = pygame.image.load("player.png").convert_alpha()

#   0 - image is looking to the right
#  90 - image is looking up
# 180 - image is looking to the left
# 270 - image is looking down
correction_angle = 90

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    player_pos  = window.get_rect().center
    player_rect = player.get_rect(center = player_pos)

    mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    dx, dy = mx - player_rect.centerx, my - player_rect.centery
    angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(-dy, dx)) - correction_angle

    rot_image      = pygame.transform.rotate(player, angle)
    rot_image_rect = rot_image.get_rect(center = player_rect.center)

    window.fill((255, 255, 255))
    window.blit(rot_image, rot_image_rect.topleft)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple block of code that you can use to help.
It uses some trigonometry and assumes the following are defined before:
elsie is the player

```
position = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    angle = math.atan2(position[1] - (elsiepos[1] + 32), position[0] - (elsiepos[0] + 26))
    elsierot = pygame.transform.rotate(elsie, 360 - angle * 57.29)
    elsiepos1 = (elsiepos[0] - elsierot.get_rect().width / 2, elsiepos[1] - elsierot.get_rect().height / 2)
    screen.blit(elsierot, elsiepos1)
```

This block should come directly after you detect keys, and should come before drawing the player, in this case, elsie.