# Still Having Problems With Rotating Cannon's Properly Towards The Player Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

[image]few people have helped me with this problem before but the rotation is still messed up my Cannons wont rotate towards the player good they are all out of place I really need help with this problem its my first time trying to make something rotate towards a player
I am trying to make my cannon mouth rotate towards player, but [the rotation is messed up](https://gyazo.com/366d55ad0e001674246471c6f6ac4fe1) and up I don't know how to fix it.

```
    class enemyshoot:
        def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        # [...............]
             self.look_at_pos = (x,y)

     def draw(self):
          # [............]
            self.rect = self.shootsright.get_rect(topleft = (self.x, self.y))

            dx = self.look_at_pos[0] - self.rect.centerx
            dy = self.look_at_pos[1] - self.rect.centery 
            angle = (180/math.pi) * math.atan2(-dx, dy)
            (window.blit(self.image, self.rect))
            self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.shootsright, angle)
            self.rect  = self.image.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)

        def lookAt( self, coordinate ):
            self.look_at_pos = coordinate
```

My full enemyshoot class

```
    shotsright = pygame.image.load("canss.png")
    class enemyshoot:
        def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
            self.x = x
            self.y =y
            self.height = height
            self.width = width
            self.color = color
            self.health = 10
            self.hitbox = (self.x + -20, self.y + 30, 31, 57)
           #-------------------------------------------------------
            # Make a Reference Copy of the bitmap for later rotation
            self.shootsright = pygame.image.load("canss.png")
            self.shootsright = pygame.transform.scale(self.shootsright,(self.shootsright.get_width()-150,self.shootsright.get_height()-150))            
            self.image    = self.shootsright
            self.rect     = self.image.get_rect()
            self.position = pygame.math.Vector2( (x, y) )
            self.isLookingAtPlayer = False
            self.look_at_pos = (x,y)
        def draw(self):
            self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
            window.blit(self.image, self.rect)
            self.rect = self.shootsright.get_rect(topleft = (self.x, self.y))

            dx = self.look_at_pos[0] - self.rect.centerx
            dy = self.look_at_pos[1] - self.rect.centery 
            angle = (180/math.pi) * math.atan2(-dy, dx)
            self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.shootsright, angle)
            self.rect  = self.image.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)

            # ------------
            self.hits = (self.x + 20, self.y, 28,60)
            pygame.draw.rect(window, (255,0,0), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 60, 100, 10)) # NEW
            pygame.draw.rect(window, (0,255,0), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 60, 100 - (5 * (10 - self.health)), 10))
            self.hitbox = (self.x + 200, self.y + 200, 51, 65)
        def lookAt( self, coordinate ):
            self.look_at_pos = coordinate


            
    black = (0,0,0)
    enemyshooting = []
    platformGroup = pygame.sprite.Group
    platformList = []
    level = ["                                                                                                                     p               p           p                         p                        p        ",
             "                                       ",
             "                             ",
             "                                      ",
             "                                  ",
             "                           ",
             "                                      ",
             "                                      ",
             "                                    ",
             "                                   ",
             "                    ",]
    for iy, row in enumerate(level):
        for ix, col in enumerate(row):
            if col == "p":
                new_platforms = enemyshoot(ix*10, iy*50, 10,10,(255,255,255))
                enemyshooting.append(new_platforms)
```

This is where the cannons rotate towards the player, wherever they are

```
            for enemyshoot in enemyshooting:
                if not enemyshoot.isLookingAtPlayer:
                    enemyshoot.lookAt((playerman.x, playerman.y))
```

Comment: [video](https://gyazo.com/619a7bca7c2a6ef303a967329985f9e2) the rotation makes the image move like I just want it to tilt its mouth towards the player now the image is starting from the bottom

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all the cannon image is far too tall. Clip the border and use a smaller image. For instance:

[image]

The center of the image is the rotation point of the canon. You can scale the image to any size you want. For instance 100x100:

```py
self.shootsright = pygame.image.load("canss.png")
self.shootsright = pygame.transform.smoothscale(self.shootsright, (100, 100))
```

See also [How to rotate an image(player) to the mouse direction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58603835/how-to-rotate-an-imageplayer-to-the-mouse-direction).

Anyway you have to *blit* the cannon after rotating the image and computing the rectangle.

```py
class enemyshoot:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        # [...]
        
        self.shootsright = pygame.image.load("canss.png")
        self.shootsright = pygame.transform.smoothscale(self.shootsright, (100, 100))            

        self.image = self.shootsright
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect(center = (self.x, self.y))
        self.look_at_pos = (self.x, self.y)

        self.hitbox = (*self.rect.topleft, *self.rect.size)

    def draw(self):
        
        dx = self.look_at_pos[0] - self.x
        dy = self.look_at_pos[1] - self.y
        angle = (180/math.pi) * math.atan2(dx, dy)
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.shootsright, angle)
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect(center = (self.x, self.y))

        window.blit(self.image, self.rect)
        self.hitbox = (*self.rect.topleft, *self.rect.size)
 
    def lookAt( self, coordinate ):
        self.look_at_pos = coordinate
```

Minimal example: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-RotateWithMouse](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-RotateWithMouse#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

Comment: yeah I did that and its still acting weird [video](https://gyazo.com/fbb0f326244fae22d5c391a088a11329)

Comment: here I have something you can debugg you just need to download the cannons I provided in the video you can see the cannons moving towards the mouse but there moving is kinda messed up like `is there a way for you to make the cannons mouth rotate toward the mouse without it moving?`  [the script](https://pastebin.com/wYUWYsN1)  and this is the video  [video](https://gyazo.com/8f814e0dc824b6b9422240d8048ab947)   and here is the cannon image          [here is the cannon image](file:///C:/Users/Habib/Desktop/PYTHONGGAME/canss.png)

Comment: oh sorry alraight give me a minut

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: @HabibIsmail I've changed the answer and I've add a canon image.

Comment: it works! but how can I change its position to lower it  [image](https://gyazo.com/2ab994a49925c5a12bb8f5e6f150cd01)  its out of my screens heightTHANK YOU SO MUCH !!!

Comment: @HabibIsmail You can do something like `self.y = y + 100` in `__init__`. If the cannon is to small, then you have to change the scale e.g. `self.shootsright = pygame.transform.smoothscale(self.shootsright, (200, 200))`

Comment: nVM THANKS I know WWWW