# Pygame Rotation size issues

Tags: python, pygame, resize, image-rotation

I am trying to rotate an image so it is facing the mouse at all times and I am noticing that the image size is changing. I am trying to troubleshoot but am having no luck. I would love some advice.

Here is what I am using:

```
ang = 360 - math.atan2(mousey - 540, mousex - 960) * 180 / math.pi
rotcircle = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.transform.rotate(redcircle,ang), [100, 100])
rect = rotcircle.get_rect(center=(960,540))
screen.blit(rotcircle,rect)
```

Comment: Related: [How do I rotate an image around its center using PyGame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183208/how-do-i-rotate-an-image-around-its-center-using-pygame/54714144#54714144) and [How to rotate an image(player) to the mouse direction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58603835/how-to-rotate-an-imageplayer-to-the-mouse-direction/58604116#58604116)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just think about it. If you rotated an image 45 degrees, for example, the surface would naturally have to be larger in order to accommodate the corners, which would otherwise stick out of the original surface's bounds. So, if you rotate the image, it's going to be larger, just as the [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.rotate) says:

> Unless rotating by 90 degree increments, **the image will be padded larger** to hold the new size. If the image has pixel alphas, the padded area will be transparent. Otherwise pygame will pick a color that matches the Surface colorkey or the topleft pixel value.

You're explicitly forcing the surface to be 100x100, meaning that the closer the image gets to being rotated by 45 degrees (again, for example), the smaller it'll appear. The easy solution is to stop resizing the image, or use another surface that's large enough to hold the rotated image and then blit the rotated image onto it.