# Image rotation while moving

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Hello I am here because I have a problem, I am learning `pygame` but my game cannot changes rotation while moving.

Using a vector didn't help.

```
 class Car(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, surf, x, y, speed, angle):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(surf, angle).convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(x, y))
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.angel=angle
        self.speed = speed
        self.image.set_colorkey(black)
    def update(self):
        if self.rect.x  > 800:
            self.rect.x=0
        elif self.rect.x <0:
            self.rect.x=800
        elif self.rect.y > 600:
            self.rect.y=0
        elif self.rect.y <0:
            self.rect.y=600
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            self.rect = self.rect.move(0, -self.speed)
        elif keys[pygame.K_s]:
            self.rect = self.rect.move(0, self.speed)
        elif keys[pygame.K_a]:
            self.rect = self.rect.move(-self.speed, 0)
            self.angel +=10
        elif keys[pygame.K_d]:
            self.rect = self.rect.move(self.speed, 0)
            self.angel -=10
```

I want to change image's angle in my class, but I can not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the original (not rotated) image in the class and store the position of the car in a [`pygame.math.Vector2`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) object:

```py
def __init__(self, surf, x, y, speed, angle):
    # [...]
    self.surf = surf.convert()
    self.surf.set_colorkey(black)
    self.pos = pygame.math.Vector2(x, y)
    # [...]
```

Chang the position of the car dependent on the direction. The direction vector is set by `self.speed` (in y direction) and has to be rotated by `self.angle`. Note that ([`.rotate()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.rotate)) rotates in counter clockwise direction. The y-axis points downwards, so when <kbd>w</kbd> is pressed, then the vector has to be subtracted and when <kbd>s</kbd> is pressed, then the vector has to be add to `self.pos`:

```py
def update(self):
 
    # [...]

    dirvec = pygame.math.Vector2(0, self.speed).rotate(self.angle)

    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        self.pos = self.pos - dirvec
    elif keys[pygame.K_s]:
        self.pos = self.pos + dirvec
```

Rotate the image and update the rectangle. See also [How do I rotate an image around its center using Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183208/how-do-i-rotate-an-image-around-its-center-using-pygame/54714144#54714144):

```py
def update(self):

    # [...]

    self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.surf, -self.angle)
    self.rect  = self.image.get_rect(center = (round(self.pos.x), round(self.pos.y)))
```

---

Full code of the class `Car`:

[image]

```py
class Car(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, surf, x, y, speed, angle):
        super().__init__()     
        self.surf = surf
        self.surf.set_colorkey(black)
        self.pos = pygame.math.Vector2(x, y)
        self.angle = angle
        self.speed = speed
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.surf, self.angle)
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect(center=(x, y))

    def update(self):

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            self.angle -= 10
        elif keys[pygame.K_d]:
            self.angle += 10

        dirvec = pygame.math.Vector2(0, self.speed).rotate(self.angle)
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            self.pos = self.pos - dirvec
        elif keys[pygame.K_s]:
            self.pos = self.pos + dirvec

        if self.pos.x > 800:
            self.pos.x = 0
        elif self.pos.x < 0:
            self.pos.x = 800
        elif self.pos.y > 600:
            self.pos.y = 0
        elif self.pos.y < 0:
            self.pos.y = 600

        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.surf, -self.angle)
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect(center = (round(self.pos.x), round(self.pos.y)))
```

---

See also [How to turn the sprite in pygame while moving with the keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64792467/how-to-turn-the-sprite-in-pygame-while-moving-with-the-keys/64792568#64792568)

<kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-CarMovement](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-CarMovement#main.py)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Make these bits:

```
elif keys[pygame.K_a]
elif keys[pygame.K_d]
```

Into:

```
if keys[pygame.K_a]
elif keys[pygame.K_d]
```

That should do it.