# Rotation not working in Pygame - Car Game

Tags: python, pygame

My car should move around the screen, which it does, but should also rotate due to direction - but this doesn't happen.

I have tried lot's of different things, but they don't work, and as i am a begginner, it would be great if someone could tell would needs to change - possibly the `Global Direction` code.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

done = False


size = (900, 570)

x =  (50)
y = (320)

x_change = 0
y_change = 0

pygame.display.set_caption('Car Racing!')
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((size))

background_image = pygame.image.load('backgroundpicture.png').convert()
bluecar = pygame.image.load('car_black_small_1.png').convert_alpha()
bluecar = pygame.transform.scale(bluecar, (20, 50))

direction = 'right'

def rotate():
    global direction
    if direction == 'right':
        pygame.transform.rotate(bluecar, 270)
    if direction == 'left':
        pygame.transform.rotate(bluecar, 90)
    if direction == 'up':
        pygame.transform.rotate(bluecar, 0)
    if direction == 'down':
        pygame.transform.rotate(bluecar, 180)

def car(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(bluecar, (x,y))


while done == False:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change = -0.25
                direction = 'left'
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 0.25
                direction = 'right'
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_change = -0.25
                direction = 'up'
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_change = 0.25
                direction = 'down'
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 0
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_change = 0
    x += x_change
    y += y_change
    gameDisplay.blit(background_image, [0,0])
    car(x,y)
    rotate()
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

I expect the car to rotate with direction of keys - ie. left key rotates car left

Comment: `pygame.transform.rotate` returns a new surface, it does not rotate the surface in-place. You need to change your calls to this function to reassign the blue car variable `bluecar  = pygame.transform.rotate(bluecar, 90)`

Comment: Hi Iain, it is coming up with this error now - 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\2018-2019\6.Coding\Python\racing car.py", line 69, in <module>
    rotate()
  File "D:\2018-2019\6.Coding\Python\racing car.py", line 28, in rotate
    bluecar = pygame.transform.rotate(bluecar, 270)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'bluecar' referenced before assignment'           Thats when i change the code to 'def rotate():
    global direction
    if direction == 'right':
        bluecar = pygame.transform.rotate(bluecar, 270)
    if direction == 'left':' and repeat.

Comment: you have to use `global bluecar` but better assign new image to new variable and always use original bluecar in rotation.

Comment: Thanks, that worked furas, but the car is very glitchy - it swaps rotations very quickly with no key presses - any way to stop this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pygame.transform.rotate`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.rotate) returns a new rotated [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html).
Don't rotate the original image, return an new and rotated image in the function `rotate`:

```py
def rotate():

    rot_image = bluecar
    if direction == 'right':
        rot_image = pygame.transform.rotate(bluecar, 270)
    if direction == 'left':
        rot_image = pygame.transform.rotate(bluecar, 90)
    if direction == 'up':
        rot_image = pygame.transform.rotate(bluecar, 0)
    if direction == 'down':
        rot_image = pygame.transform.rotate(bluecar, 180)

    return rot_image
```

See alos [How do I rotate an image around its center using Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183208/how-do-i-rotate-an-image-around-its-center-using-pygame/54714144#54714144)

Rotate the image in the function `car` and get the [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) of the image by [`.get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) and set the center to (`x`, `y`):

```py
def car(x,y):
    rot_image = rotate()
    rect = rot_image.get_rect(center = (x,y))
    gameDisplay.blit(rot_image, rect)
```

---

The answer to [Image rotation while moving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57226587/image-rotation-while-moving/57227063#57227063) is related a d shows how to use a 
[`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) for a moving car.

Use the class [`Car`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57226587/image-rotation-while-moving/57227063#57227063) from the link and create a car object and add the car to a [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) before the wain loop. `.update()` and `.draw()` the group in the loop:

```py
car = Car(bluecar, x, y, 5, 0)
group = pygame.sprite.Group(car) 

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while done == False:
    clock.tick(60)

    # [...]

    gameDisplay.blit(background_image, [0,0])

    group.update()
    group.draw(gameDisplay)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: hi rabbid, can you help me with the pygame.sprite.Sprite thing

Comment: @TomBaker I extended the answer. See the last part.

Comment: sorry rabbid, i don't understand the car class bit

Comment: @TomBaker What do you mean by *"don't understand"*. Follow the link and copy the class, that's it.