# How to turn the sprite in pygame while moving with the keys

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, turn, pygame-surface

So basically ive been hoping it would be possible to effectively turn your sprite while moving it around with <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>. Any ideas because im certainly stumped, thanks!

Comment: @JamesHuang *"You will have to do a bit of math to get it around the center "* - it is trivial. See the answer.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Got the basic concept, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [How do I rotate an image around its center using PyGame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183208/how-do-i-rotate-an-image-around-its-center-using-pygame/54714144#54714144) for rotating a surface. If you want to rotate an image around a center point (*cx*, *cy*) you can just do that:

```py
rotated_car = pygame.transform.rotate(car, angle)
window.blit(rotated_car, rotated_car.get_rect(center = (cx, cy))
```

Use `pygame.math.Vector2` to store the `position` and the `direction` of movement. Change the `position` by the current `direction` when <kbd>w</kbd> respectively <kbd>s</kbd> is pressed. Change the angle of the `direction` vector with [`rotate_ip`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.rotate_ip), when <kbd>a</kbd> respectively <kbd>d</kbd> is pressed:

```py
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_w]:
    position += direction
if keys[pygame.K_s]:
    position -= direction
if keys[pygame.K_a]:
    direction.rotate_ip(-1)
if keys[pygame.K_d]:
    direction.rotate_ip(1)
```

See also:

- [Motion and movement](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame/pygame_movement_and_motion.md)
- [Image rotation while moving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57226587/image-rotation-while-moving/57227063#57227063)

---

Minimal example: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-CarMovement](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-CarMovement#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

car = pygame.image.load('CarRed64.png')
position = pygame.math.Vector2(window.get_rect().center)
direction = pygame.math.Vector2(5, 0)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        position += direction
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        position -= direction
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        direction.rotate_ip(-1)
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        direction.rotate_ip(1)

    window.fill(0)
    angle = direction.angle_to((1, 0))
    rotated_car = pygame.transform.rotate(car, angle)
    window.blit(rotated_car, rotated_car.get_rect(center = (round(position.x), round(position.y))))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```