# How do I move a character based on it's rotation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, pygame, game-development

I have a character in PyGame which I want to move forward depending on its rotation. Currently it's very strange and wonky.

Here's all my code: https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/enapuravet.lua

Here's the relevent code:

```
    def rotate(self, amount):
        self.rotation += amount
        if self.rotation == 181:
            self.rotation = -180
        elif self.rotation == -181:
            self.rotation = 180
        print(self.rotation)
        self.capybara = pygame.transform.rotate(self.base_capybara, self.rotation)
        self.rect = self.capybara.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)

    def move_forward(self, speed):
        print(self.rotation)
        new_coordinates = calculate_new_xy((self.x, self.y), 2, self.rotation*(math.pi/180))
        self.x = new_coordinates[0]
        self.y = new_coordinates[1]
        self.rect = self.capybara.get_rect(center = (self.x, self.y))

def calculate_new_xy(old_xy,speed,angle_in_radians):
    print(angle_in_radians)
    new_x = old_xy[0] + (speed*math.cos(angle_in_radians))
    new_y = old_xy[1] + (speed*math.sin(angle_in_radians))
    return new_x, new_y
```

Here's what it does:
https://gyazo.com/3b7bf1c5b2e760a53913b6d3acae6e67

I also tried some other x_y calculating functions like this:

```
    move_vec = pygame.math.Vector2()
move_vec.from_polar((speed, angle_in_degrees))
return old_xy + move_vec
```

but they had the same/very similar results.

This is the capybara:

[image: capybara]

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [mcve]. In particular, be sure to include the `class` line which contains the two methods and show how all variables are initialized.

Comment: Your `calculate_new_xy()` is mathematically correct. However, there are quirks of floating point arithmetic that might be causing the issue you see here. I suggest debugging your code to find out what it is doing. Do a few calculations by hand to get the values you expect for a specific rotation that isn't working right and compare with the results your code gives. [This article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) has some great tips to get you started if you are unfamiliar with debugging techniques.

Comment: Here's a handy python trick: `self.x, self.y = calculate_new_xy(...)` is the same as the 3 lines you have here.

Comment: Hmm. Ok. Is the looping rotation stuff correct? Should it be -180 to +180?

Comment: What looping? There is no loop in the code you show here.

Comment: I meant wrapping, I guess.
The "if self.rotation == 181:" ...

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong. As I said, you will need to debug your code with `print()` statements or a visual debugger to figure out what's going on here.

Comment: See [Image rotation while moving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57226587/image-rotation-while-moving/57227063#57227063), [Move Character with Vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65688244/move-character-with-vector/65688573#65688573) and [How to turn the sprite in pygame while moving with the keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64792467/how-to-turn-the-sprite-in-pygame-while-moving-with-the-keys/64792568#64792568)   and

Comment: Oh...the 181 changing to -180 is a little weird. Maybe it should be -179.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) is supposed to represent an area on the screen, a `pygame.Rect` object can only store integral data.

> The coordinates for Rect objects are all integers. [...]

If you want to store object positions with floating point accuracy, you have to store the location of the object in separate variables respectively attributes and to synchronize the `pygame.Rect` object. [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) the coordinates and assign it to the location (e.g. `.center`) of the rectangle.

The unit of the angle of `math.sin` and `math.cos` is Randian. You needs to convert the angle from degrees to radians with `math.radians`:

```py
class Capybara:
    def __init__(self, size_multiplier):
        # [...]

        self.x, self.y = 300, 300
        self.rect = self.capybara.get_rect(center = (round(self.x), round(self.y)))

    def rotate(self, amount):
        self.rotation += amount
        ifv self.rotation > 360:
            self.rotation -= 360
        elif self.rotation < 0:
            self.rotation += 360
        self.capybara = pygame.transform.rotate(self.base_capybara, self.rotation)
        self.rect = self.capybara.get_rect(center = (round(self.x), round(self.y)))
        
    def move(self, move):
        self.x += move * math.cos(math.radians(self.rotation + 90))
        self.y -= move * math.sin(math.radians(self.rotation + 90))
```

See also [Move Character with Vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65688244/move-character-with-vector/65688573#65688573), [Image rotation while moving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57226587/image-rotation-while-moving/57227063#57227063) or [How to turn the sprite in pygame while moving with the keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64792467/how-to-turn-the-sprite-in-pygame-while-moving-with-the-keys/64792568#64792568).

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame, math
pygame.init()

size = width, height = 600, 600
green = 50, 168, 82

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

class Capybara:
    def __init__(self, size_multiplier):
        self.capybara = pygame.image.load('capybara.png')
        self.o_size = 92, 206
        self.new_size = (self.o_size[0] * size_multiplier,self.o_size[1] * size_multiplier)
        self.capybara = pygame.transform.scale(self.capybara, self.new_size)
        self.base_capybara = self.capybara
        self.rotation = 0
        self.x, self.y = 300, 300
        self.rect = self.capybara.get_rect(center = (round(self.x), round(self.y)))

    def rotate(self, amount):
        self.rotation += amount
        if self.rotation > 360:
            self.rotation -= 360
        elif self.rotation < 0:
            self.rotation += 360
        self.capybara = pygame.transform.rotate(self.base_capybara, self.rotation)
        self.rect = self.capybara.get_rect(center = (round(self.x), round(self.y)))
        
    def move(self, move):
        self.x += move * math.cos(math.radians(self.rotation + 90))
        self.y -= move * math.sin(math.radians(self.rotation + 90))


capybara = Capybara(0.8)

fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

rotate_l = False
rotate_r = False

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

            quit()

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    rotate = keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] - keys[pygame.K_LEFT]
    move = keys[pygame.K_DOWN] - keys[pygame.K_UP]
    capybara.move(-move * 5)
    capybara.rotate(-rotate)

    screen.fill(green)
    screen.blit(capybara.capybara, capybara.rect)
    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Wonderful!!
{
        angle += 1

        # Rotate the player sprite
        player_rect = player.get_rect(topleft=(player_x, player_y))

        # Rotate the player's head
        head_rott = pygame.transform.rotate(player_head, angle)
        rotated_head_rect = head_rott.get_rect(center=(player_x, player_y))