# Pygame crashes after only a few seconds of rendering my code

Tags: python, pygame, crash

For some reason, this program crashes after only a second or so of running this. Funnily enough, changing the turnAngle or fps affects how long it lasts before crashing. The error it throws is a
`ValueError: subsurface rectangle outside of surface area` on line 29 / line 9. Any ideas?

```
import pygame as pg


def rot_center(image, angle):
    orig_rect = image.get_rect()
    rot_image = pg.transform.rotate(image, angle)
    rot_rect = orig_rect.copy()
    rot_rect.center = rot_image.get_rect().center
    rot_image = rot_image.subsurface(rot_rect).copy()
    return rot_image


pg.init()

mainDisplay = pg.display.set_mode([600, 376])

imgSplashBG = pg.image.load('guiAssets/splash/BG.png')
imgSplashFG = pg.image.load('guiAssets/splash/FG.png')
imgSplashRedCircle = pg.image.load('guiAssets/splash/redCircle.png')
imgSplashGreenCircle = pg.image.load('guiAssets/splash/greenCircle.png')

turnAngle = 10

frame = 0
clock = pg.time.Clock()
crashed = False
while not crashed:
    frame += 1
    mainDisplay.blit(imgSplashBG, (0, 0))
    mainDisplay.blit(rot_center(imgSplashGreenCircle, ((frame % 360) * 10)), (-189, -189))
    mainDisplay.blit(rot_center(imgSplashRedCircle, ((frame % 360) * 10)), (453, 230))
    mainDisplay.blit(imgSplashFG, (0, 0))
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)
```

Comment: No, that answer doesn't really apply to my code. This is actually super confusing to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [How do I rotate an image around its center using PyGame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183208/how-do-i-rotate-an-image-around-its-center-using-pygame/54714144#54714144)

Furthermore you have to handle the events in the application loop. See [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) respectively [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump):

> For each frame of your game, you will need to make some sort of call to the event queue. This ensures your program can internally interact with the rest of the operating system.

For instance:

```py
import pygame as pg

def rot_center(image, angle, center):
    rotated_image = pg.transform.rotate(image, angle)
    new_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(center = center)
    return rotated_image, new_rect

pg.init()
mainDisplay = pg.display.set_mode([600, 376])

imgSplashBG = pg.image.load('guiAssets/splash/BG.png')
imgSplashFG = pg.image.load('guiAssets/splash/FG.png')
imgSplashRedCircle = pg.image.load('guiAssets/splash/redCircle.png')
imgSplashGreenCircle = pg.image.load('guiAssets/splash/greenCircle.png')

turnAngle = 10
frame = 0

clock = pg.time.Clock()
run = True
crashed = False
while not crashed and run:

    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            run = False

    frame += 1
    angle = (frame*turnAngle) % 360
    centerGreen = (189, 189)
    centerRed = (453, 230)

    mainDisplay.blit(imgSplashBG, (0, 0))
    mainDisplay.blit( *rot_center(imgSplashGreenCircle, angle, centerGreen) )
    mainDisplay.blit( *rot_center(imgSplashRedCircle, angle,centerRed) )
    mainDisplay.blit(imgSplashFG, (0, 0))
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Incredible! I have no idea why but that completely fixed the problem. I can't believe I forgot to add that.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add a time variable before your loop 'while not'

Like this :

```
.....
frame = 0
clock = pg.time.Clock()
time = pg.time.get_ticks()      #here
crashed = False
while not .....
```

Comment: I went ahead and added that line, but it still crashes.