# Why does it say that top left is not defined in a function pygame?

Tags: python, function, pygame, image-rotation, pygame-surface

I'm using Python 2.7 and I'm also using Pygame. I've been wanting to rotate an image and this is what I've got so far.

```py
import pygame, random
from random import randint
# add parking lot, hunger bar, water bar, shops, drive-thrus, etc...
# add AI car/cars, police cars when going over 30 speed at the road(5 speed in parking lot/drive thru), does not crash when hitting building/other cars(only gets hit back)
# make turning animation
pygame.init()

done = False

x = 465
when = 0
road_stripe_y = 0
road_stripe_y2 = 250
road_stripe_y3 = 500
road_stripe_y4 = 700
speed = 0
gear = 1
ai_car_y = 0
parking_lot_y = -400
player_angle = 0

ground = (50, 100, 0)
road = (64, 64, 64)
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 800))
screen.fill(ground)

player = pygame.image.load('racing car copy.png')
ai_car = pygame.image.load('ai_racing car.png')
road_stripe = pygame.image.load('costume1 copy.png')

font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 40)
text = font.render('Gear', True, black, ground)
text2 = font.render(str(gear), True, black, ground)
text2_rect = text2.get_rect()
text_rect = text.get_rect()
text_rect.center = (100, 100)
text2_rect.center = (100, 150)

screen.blit(player, (x, 600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def rotate(screen, player, topleft, player_angle):
    rotated_player = pygame.transform.rotate(player, player_angle)
    new_player_rect = rotated_player.get_rect(center = player.get_rect(topleft = topleft).center)
    screen.blit(rotated_player, new_player_rect.topleft)

while not done == True:
    global gear
    global left
    global right
    pygame.event.get()
    pygame.display.flip()
    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if pressed[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
        done = True
    if pressed[pygame.K_a]:
        if not x >= 670 and not speed == 0:
            x += speed/4
    if pressed[pygame.K_d] and not speed == 0:
        if not x <= 280:
            x -= speed/4
    rotate(screen, player, topleft, player_angle)
    player_collison_box = player.get_rect(topleft=(x, 600))
    if pressed[pygame.K_w]:
        if not speed >= 5 and gear == 1:
            speed += 1
        elif not speed >= 15 and gear == 2:
            speed += 1
        elif not speed >= 30 and gear == 3:
            speed += 1
        elif not speed >= 40 and gear == 4:
            speed += 1
        elif not speed >= 80 and gear == 5:
            speed += 1
    else:
        if not speed <= 0:
            speed -= 1
    if speed >= 15 and gear == 2:
        speed -= 1
    if speed >= 5 and gear == 1:
        speed -= 1
    if speed >= 30 and gear == 3:
        speed -= 1
    if speed >= 40 and gear == 4:
        speed -= 1
    if speed >= 80 and gear == 5:
        speed -= 1
    if pressed[pygame.K_1]:
        gear = 1
    elif pressed[pygame.K_2]:
        gear = 2
    elif pressed[pygame.K_3]:
        gear = 3
    elif pressed[pygame.K_4]:
        gear = 4
    elif pressed[pygame.K_5]:
        gear = 5
    screen.fill(ground)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, road, (240 + x - 465, 0, 500, 1000))
    parking_lot_y += speed
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, road, (400, parking_lot_y, 600, 800))
    screen.blit(road_stripe, (490 + x - 465, road_stripe_y))
    screen.blit(road_stripe, (490 + x - 465, road_stripe_y2))
    screen.blit(road_stripe, (490 + x - 465, road_stripe_y3))
    screen.blit(road_stripe, (490 + x - 465, road_stripe_y4))
    road_stripe_y += speed
    road_stripe_y2 += speed
    road_stripe_y3 += speed
    road_stripe_y4 += speed
    if road_stripe_y >= 850:
        road_stripe_y = -100
    if road_stripe_y2 >= 850:
        road_stripe_y2 = -100
    if road_stripe_y3 >= 850:
        road_stripe_y3 = -100
    if road_stripe_y4 >= 850:
        road_stripe_y4 = -100
    ai_car_y += speed + 30
    if ai_car_y >= 3000:
        ai_car_y = -100
    screen.blit(player, (465, 600))
    text2 = font.render(str(gear), True, black, ground)
    screen.blit(text, text_rect)
    screen.blit(text2, text2_rect)
    screen.blit(ai_car, (325 + x - 465, ai_car_y))
    clock.tick(40)

pygame.quit()
```

This is what calls the function:

```py
rotate(screen, player, topleft, player_angle)
```

I don't know what the problem is, but it says that 'topleft' isn't defined. It's really confusing because shouldn't topleft be defined on its own when I imported Pygame? I couldn't find any useful answers on the internet so can you help me?

Comment: I think it's either 1.9.6 or 2.0.0, I don't even know if there is a 2.0.0. It's the newest version, anyways

Comment: the line that causes the error is the one that calls it.

Comment: The problem isn't in the `rotate()` function itself.  You're trying to _call_ that function with an argument named `topleft`, and that variable does not exist in the caller.

Comment: Then I don't really know how to do the line that says `new_player_rect = rotated_player.get_rect(center = player.get_rect(topleft = topleft).center)` because then the `topleft` throws an error

Comment: Show us the entire calling function, if you can.

Comment: what do you mean? I've already shown the whole thing. The rest of my code would be the while loop and whatever else is in it.

Comment: Show us the code that has this line: `rotate(screen, player, topleft, player_angle)`

Comment: that's the entire thing. Do I not call functions correctly? or would you want me to just show my entire code?

Comment: Yes, show your entire code.  I didn't mean just that one single line.

Comment: *"the line that causes the error is the one that calls it."* - So you haven't declared `topleft`. `topleft` has t o be a tuple with the x and y coordinate.

Comment: right I'm gonna edit the question above.....

Comment: Okay now I'm really confused, because that code does not have the line `rotate(screen, player, topleft, player_angle)` at all.

Comment: yes it does, it's near the top of the while loop

Comment: No, it has the line `rotate(screen, player, player_angle)`.  That is not the same.

Comment: oh yeah... I forgot. I took away the 'topleft'. Do you want me to put it back?

Comment: It's very hard to help if you don't show us the actual code that is causing the error.

Comment: well, this is what the error says, I think this will help.... ```File "/Users/max/PycharmProjects/Game2/main.py", line 47, in rotate
    new_player_rect = rotated_player.get_rect(center = player.get_rect(topleft = topleft).center)
NameError: global name 'topleft' is not defined```

Comment: You modified the definition of the `rotate` function to take away the `topleft` parameter, so of course that is an undefined variable.

Comment: I've put it back but it now says ```File "/Users/max/PycharmProjects/Game2/main.py", line 65, in <module>
    rotate(screen, player, topleft, player_angle)
NameError: name 'topleft' is not defined```

Comment: Please update the question to have the real actual code that's causing the problem.  It's very hard to keep track of code modifications in the comments.

Comment: right, I've done it and I'm just going to check out if Rabbid76's answer works

Comment: In the while loop, when you call `rotate(screen, player, topleft, player_angle)`, you have not defined any variable named `topleft`.  I don't know how to explain it any clearer than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the argument `topleft` to the function `rotate`. Pass `(x, 600)` to the argument:

```py
def rotate(screen, player, topleft, player_angle):
    rect = player.get_rect(topleft = topleft)
    rotated_player = pygame.transform.rotate(player, player_angle)
    new_player_rect = rotated_player.get_rect(center = rect.center)
    screen.blit(rotated_player, new_player_rect.topleft)
```

```py
rotate(screen, player, (x, 600), player_angle)
player_collison_box = player.get_rect(topleft=(x, 600))
```

---

I recommend to return the collision box from the function `rotate`:

```py
def rotate(screen, player, topleft, player_angle):
    rect = player.get_rect(topleft = topleft)
    rotated_player = pygame.transform.rotate(player, player_angle)
    new_player_rect = rotated_player.get_rect(center = rect.center)
    screen.blit(rotated_player, new_player_rect.topleft)
    return new_player_rect
```

```py
player_collison_box = rotate(screen, player, (x, 600), player_angle)
```

---

See [How do I rotate an image around its center using PyGame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183208/how-do-i-rotate-an-image-around-its-center-using-pygame/54714144#54714144)