# Why is my Pygame sprite rotating like a collision box?

Tags: python, pygame, rotation, pygame-surface, blit

Right, so this is out of all the questions and bugs I have had in Python/Pygame, the strangest one to me. So I just learned how to rotate something in Pygame and it was working fine with everything else except this one sprite.

This is what rotates it: `rotated_roads = pygame.transform.rotate(roads, angle)`

This is what blits it: `screen.blit(rotated_roads, (240 + x - 465, 0))`

I don't know what the problem is, but it's not rotating the way I was expecting it to; to me, it kind of looked like it was rotating like a collision box. [The sprite's shape is a rectangle] I don't know what the problem is, so can you help me??

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't rotate around its center? Or is it not transparent?

Comment: uh.. well I suppose you could call that "not rotating around its center", but I'm not really familiar with this kind of stuff so I'm not too sure.

Comment: So why do you not use the code from your previous question? - [Why is it not blitting a sprite in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65045730/why-is-it-not-blitting-a-sprite-in-pygame)

Comment: What do you expect by `(240 + x - 465, 0)`?

Comment: well, the `(240 + x - 465, 0)` definitely isn't causing the problem, my other rotating sprites using `(240 + x 465, 0)` as well and they don't have this problem.... I think. The other rotating sprites are much smaller.

Comment: I am using the same code as the last question, but for some reason this particular sprite doesn't seem the work.... Now I"m starting to think that it's got nothing to do with the code but it's because the costume itself is off-center

Comment: No The code in the question does not rotate around the center.

Comment: oh, well this rotation thing it still pretty confusing....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [How do I rotate an image around its center using PyGame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183208/how-do-i-rotate-an-image-around-its-center-using-pygame/54714144#54714144).

Get the rectangle of the original image and set the position. Get the rectangle of the rotated image and set the center position through the center of the original rectangle:

```py
rotated_roads = pygame.transform.rotate(roads, angle)
rect = roads.get_rect(topleft = (240 + x - 465, 0))
rotated_rect = rotated_roads.get_rect(center = rect.center)
screen.blit(rotated_roads, rotated_rect)
```