# How to draw a rotated ellipse using Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

[image]

Here given the code I use to draw a rectangle and an ellipse within it.(Purple one).

```py
pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, [50, 50, 500, 200], 2)
pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, BLACK, [50, 50, 500, 200], 2)
```

I need to draw a rotated ellipse like my green image.
Is there a code I can use in pygame for that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no direct way to draw a rotated shape. [`pygame.transform.rotate()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.rotate) can rotate a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object but you cannot rotate a shape directly. You need to draw the shape on a *Surface* and rotate that *Surface*:

1. Create a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object with a **per-pixel alpha format** and with the size of the shape.
2. Draw the shapeon the _Surface.
3. Rotate the *Surface* with the shape around its center. See [How do I rotate an image around its center using PyGame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183208/how-do-i-rotate-an-image-around-its-center-using-pygame/54714144#54714144)
4. [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) the *Surface* with the shapeonto the target *Surface*.

Write a functions that draws the rotated shapes:

```py
def draw_rect_angle(surface, color, rect, angle, width=0):
    target_rect = pygame.Rect(rect)
    shape_surf = pygame.Surface(target_rect.size, pygame.SRCALPHA)
    pygame.draw.rect(shape_surf, color, (0, 0, *target_rect.size), width)
    rotated_surf = pygame.transform.rotate(shape_surf, angle)
    surface.blit(rotated_surf, rotated_surf.get_rect(center = target_rect.center))
```

```
def draw_ellipse_angle(surface, color, rect, angle, width=0):
    target_rect = pygame.Rect(rect)
    shape_surf = pygame.Surface(target_rect.size, pygame.SRCALPHA)
    pygame.draw.ellipse(shape_surf, color, (0, 0, *target_rect.size), width)
    rotated_surf = pygame.transform.rotate(shape_surf, angle)
    surface.blit(rotated_surf, rotated_surf.get_rect(center = target_rect.center))
```

Use the functions:

```py
angle = 30
draw_rect_angle(screen, BLACK, [50, 50, 500, 200], angle, 2)
draw_ellipse_angle(screen, BLACK, [50, 50, 500, 200], angle, 2)
```

### [image]

Minimal example:

```py
import pygame
import test

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def draw_rect_angle(surface, color, rect, angle, width=0):
    target_rect = pygame.Rect(rect)
    shape_surf = pygame.Surface(target_rect.size, pygame.SRCALPHA)
    pygame.draw.rect(shape_surf, color, (0, 0, *target_rect.size), width)
    rotated_surf = pygame.transform.rotate(shape_surf, angle)
    surface.blit(rotated_surf, rotated_surf.get_rect(center = target_rect.center))

def draw_ellipse_angle(surface, color, rect, angle, width=0):
    target_rect = pygame.Rect(rect)
    shape_surf = pygame.Surface(target_rect.size, pygame.SRCALPHA)
    pygame.draw.ellipse(shape_surf, color, (0, 0, *target_rect.size), width)
    rotated_surf = pygame.transform.rotate(shape_surf, angle)
    surface.blit(rotated_surf, rotated_surf.get_rect(center = target_rect.center))

angle = 00
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    window_center = window.get_rect().center

    window.fill((255, 255, 255))
    draw_rect_angle(window, (0, 0, 0), (75, 150, 250, 100), angle, 2)
    draw_ellipse_angle(window, (0, 0, 0), (75, 150, 250, 100), angle, 2)
    angle += 1
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: got it. This is helpful.