# Get sprite angle with pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have a little problem with pygame. I am actually coding a project with pygame and I would like to know how could I know the angle of a sprite because `pygame.transfrom.rotate(self.player.image, 50)` is rotating it for 50 degrees from the angle that it is at actually, but i would like to rotate it from zero. so I thought I could just substract the  angle of the sprite to itself to make it zero but I cant find how to find the angle of the sprite.
Could someone help me please ?

Comment: self.player.rotation?

Comment: If you rotate the same image multiple times it will lose quality. It's recommended to keep an unrotated copy and rotate that to a rotation value when needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot get the angle from an image ([`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html)). A *Surface* is always rectangular. [`pygame.transform.rotate`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.rotate) creates a new but slightly larger surface. The size of the new *Surface* is the size of the rotated rectangle's axi-aligned bounding box.
If you want to know how the image was rotated, you need to store the angle in an attribute.

Anyway, never rotate an image that has already been rotated. This leads to weird distortions. See [How do I rotate an image around its center using PyGame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183208/how-do-i-rotate-an-image-around-its-center-using-pygame/54714144#54714144).

Store the original image in an attribute. e.g.:

```py
class MySprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, image):
        super().__init__() 
        self.original_image = image
        self.image = self.original_image
        self.rect = self.image.get_tect(center = (x, y))
        self.angle = 0

    def roatate(self, angle):
        self.angle = angle
        self.image = pygame.transfrom.rotate(self.original_image, slef.angle)
        self.rect = self.image.get_tect(center = (x, y))

    def resetRotate(self):
        self.rotate(0)
```