# pygame copy image, then rotate it

Tags: python, pygame

I have one picture which I want to use multiple times on the screen but it always has to be rotated differently. If I use the pygame.image.rotate function it rotates the imported image so I can't rotate every image on its own. Is there any way I can copy it in the code and then rotate it?

```py
> image = pygame.image.load("assets/image")  
pygame.transform.rotate(image, 20) #rotated by 20 deg  
pygame.transform.rotate(image, 20) #rotated by 20  + 20 deg  
#what i want  
copy(pygame.transform.rotate(image, 20))
```

Comment: Do you have more specifics? Maybe a section of your code you think is most relevant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`pygame.transform.rotate`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html) does not rotate the image itself. This function creates a rotated copy of the image and returns the copy:

```py
image = pygame.image.load("assets/image") 
rotated_image_copy = pygame.transform.rotate(image, 20)
```

If you want to create multiple rotated images, you must always rotate the original image. See also [How do I rotate an image around its center using PyGame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183208/how-do-i-rotate-an-image-around-its-center-using-pygame/54714144#54714144).

Create a list of images:

```py
image = pygame.image.load("assets/image")
image_list = [pygame.transform.rotate(image, ang) for ang in range(0, 360, 20)]
```