# Rotating a sprite on pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have created a class for the zombie I blit into the screen, but the rotation does not work at all, it rotates a lot and moves the image around, is there some way to rotate the image around its center? how could I change the rotate def so that it works properly?

```
class zombieObj:
    def __init__(self, x, y, vel, angle):
      tempZombie = pygame.image.load('zombieSprite.png')
      self.zombieSpriteSurface = pygame.transform.scale(tempZombie, (64, 64))
      self.x = x
      self.y = y
      self.vel = 1
      self.angle = angle
    def rotate(self, image, angle):
      self.zombieSpriteSurface = pygame.transform.rotate(image, angle)
```

and this is how I called it in the loop:

```
zombieSprite.angle = zombieSprite.angle + 5
zombieSprite.rotate(zombieSprite.zombieSpriteSurface, zombieSprite.angle)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [How do I rotate an image around its center using PyGame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183208/how-do-i-rotate-an-image-around-its-center-using-pygame/54714144#54714144). The trick is to get the center of the image before rotation and set it after rotation. Also, you need to rotate the original image to avoid distortion:

```py
class ZombieObj:
    def __init__(self, x, y, vel, angle):
        tempZombie = pygame.image.load('zombieSprite.png')
        self.originalImage = pygame.transform.scale(tempZombie, (64, 64))
        self.vel = 1
        self.angle = 0
        self.rect = self.originalImage.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))
        self.roatate(angle)

    def rotate(self, angle):
        self.angle = angle
        self.zombieSpriteSurface = pygame.transform.rotate(self.originalImage, self.angle)
        self.rect = self.zombieSpriteSurface.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
```

If you want to increase the rotation by a certain angle, you need to add the additional angle to the current angle:

```py
class ZombieObj:
    # [...]

    def rotate(self, deltaAngle):
        self.angle += deltaAngle
        self.zombieSpriteSurface = pygame.transform.rotate(self.originalImage, self.angle)
        self.rect = self.zombieSpriteSurface.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
```